# CSS Vertical Centering using Absolute Center or Flexbox or Translate not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know this question has been asked over and over again.
I am trying to center a text container vertically with CSS, but nothing works. Is it because of the fluid negative margin layout? What am i getting wrong?

The Text Container c-service__body is in maximized view (code snippet) never fully centered.

Thanks a lot.

1. Using the Absolute and bot, left, top, right:0 method : (Desktop: Space at the Bottom)

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45.83333%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.16667%;
}

.c-block__item {
  position: relative;
}

.c-block__body {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Using the translate method: (Desktop: Heading is jumping up into infinity)

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45.83333%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.16667%;
}

.c-block__item {
  position: relative;
}

.c-block__body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Using Flexbox ( Desktop Fullscreen : more space at the Bottom )

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45.83333%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.16667%;
}

.c-block__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about sticking to *one* question?

Comment: I tried to understand if there is a connection between the issues, thats why i posted the 3 regular ways i knew about...wasn't meant to confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need first both boxes be the same height, then to vertical-align content inside (aside the other one ) makes it easy

flex can be inbricated and float avoided

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.c-block {
  display:flex;
  }
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45.83333%;
  margin-left: 4.16667%;
}

.c-block__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or disply:table can be used

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.c-block {
  display:table;
  }
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
  display:table-cell;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  display:table-cell;
  padding-left: 4.16667%;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but you can also use inline block to align each boxe to their center:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.c-block__item {display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think floating the elements is what's causing problems for you.

Would this work for you?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/rjVwyR)

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c-block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.c-block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45.83333%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-block">
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/414/">
  </div>
  <div class="c-block__item">
    <div class="c-block__body">
      <h2>asdasdasd</h2>
      <p>lorem bababakbakabkabakbaka asdasdadasd sadasdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdasdasdasd asd asdasdasdasdasd
      </p>
      <p>asdasdasdasd aösdköalskdölaksdölkasödlk asdasdasdölmölm
        asdasdasdasdasdasdölkölkölk
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works in codepen, i am using susy for a fluid grid, in the main layout it somehow doesn't work, even forced with !important ...i just don't get it..i might have to ditch the float then and go fully flex for that section...what i actually wanted to avoid.. thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not familiar with susy, and can't offer any more help without seeing more code or the site itself. Feel free to post more info if you want. Best of luck

Comment: thanks a lot i think i found something : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394133/susy2-sass-centering-elements-vertically-inside-grid-columns . i will try it and if it worked report here... thanks a lot